# Is there an easy way to watch selected local PHP files for content changes on Windows?

Tags: php, version-control, ide

Is there any easy way (tool or IDE plugin or some other solution for MS Win) how to watch selected local PHP files for local changes of content?

I am developing a PHP application based on open source core which is developed independently and distributed only in zip files so I need to make update manually by overwriting of old version with the new one.

The problem occurs when I make my own changes to core PHP files and during making updates to the current version of the core I rewrite these files with their new version, I do not know which changed files were previously modified by me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it **is** an easy obvious way

1. *Any* VCS, which support branches
2. [Vendor branches](https://edoras.sdsu.edu/doc/svn-book-html-chunk/svn.advanced.vendorbr.html) + branches diff|merge